# Swift - Not enough bits to represent the passed value

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

Below code works fine on iOS devices and watchOS simulator.

```
static func getEventDateTime(startDateTime: Date?) -> String {
    if let startDateTime = startDateTime {
        let startTimeInMillis = Int(startDateTime.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        let fiveMinutesInMillis = 300000
        let eventStartDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval((startTimeInMillis-fiveMinutesInMillis)/1000))

        return convertDateToString(eventStartDateTime)
    }
    
    return ""
}
```

However when I run it on Apple Watch Series 3, I get the following error: `double value cannot be converted to int because the result would be greater than int.max` on line `let startTimeInMillis = Int(startDateTime.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)`.

So I changed
`let startTimeInMillis = Int(startDateTime.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)` to `let startTimeInMillis = Int64(startDateTime.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)`

and

`let eventStartDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval((startTimeInMillis-fiveMinutesInMillis)/1000))` to `let eventStartDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval((Int(startTimeInMillis)-fiveMinutesInMillis)/1000))`.

Now I am getting following error: Not enough bits to represent the passed value on line `let eventStartDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval((Int(startTimeInMillis)-fiveMinutesInMillis)/1000))`

How do I change the function to make it work on Apple Watch Series 3 or watchOS 7?

***Updated function code:***

```
  static func getEventDateTime(startDateTime: Date?) -> String {
    if let startDateTime = startDateTime {
        let startTimeInMillis = Int64(startDateTime.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        let fiveMinutesInMillis = 300000
        let eventStartDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval((Int(startTimeInMillis)-fiveMinutesInMillis)/1000))

        return convertDateToString(eventStartDateTime)
    }
    
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Watch 3 has a 32 bit architecture. Is `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` (01.01.2001) instead of `timeIntervalSince1970` (01.01.1970) a solution? Or maybe the `Decimal` type is an option.

Comment: Do you need to use millisecond precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Calendar API to add/subtract time units (doesn't support milliseconds, but does support nanoseconds, which can be converted from): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar.

```
func getEventDateTimeCal(startDateTime: Date?) -> String {
  if let startDateTime = startDateTime,
     let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -5, to: startDateTime) {
    return convertDateToString(date, startDateTime)
  }
  return ""
}
```

But also, if you don't need millisecond precision, subtract seconds from TimeInterval. Note that [TimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval) is `typealias TimeInterval = Double` and always represents seconds.

```
func getEventDateTime(startDateTime: Date?) -> String {
  if let startDateTime = startDateTime {
    let fiveMinutesInSeconds = 5.0 * 60
    let eventStartDateTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: startDateTime.timeIntervalSince1970 - fiveMinutesInSeconds)

    return convertDateToString(startDateTime, eventStartDateTime)
  }

  return ""
}
```